# My didSelectRowAtIndexPath function causes memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

My first post here. Seems I have run into a bit of a memory leak problem.

I have a tab bar with two columns, one for salad and one for sushi. In each tab I also have a tableview that displays the different food choices. When the user presses one of the cells the app takes the user to a more detailview that displays a larger image and some info about the chosen food menu.

But when I run leaks I get a 98,5% leak on the following line. 
[self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
if I release detail after this line, the app crashes.

Here is the rest of the function code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *message = nil;
NSMutableString *image_string = nil;

DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailview"];

if(tableView == SushiTable)
{
    message = [sushiNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    image_string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[sushiImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
if(tableView == SaladTable)
{
    message = [saladNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    image_string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[saladImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

[image_string deleteCharactersInRange: [image_string rangeOfString: @"_small"]];

NSMutableString *temp_str = [[message copy] autorelease];
NSString *final = [[[temp_str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ä" withString:@"a"] 
                   lowercaseString];

detail.food_name = message;
detail.image_name = image_string;
detail.food_info_key = final;

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
detail = nil;

}
```

EDIT:
I saw also that in my viewDidLoad function in DetailViewController the following line has a memory leak, don't know if it's maybe related.

```
food_image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_name];
```

EDIT2:
Also I'm running on the simulator.

Comment: You could try an `autorelease`

Comment: DetailViewController *detail = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailview"] autorelease] ;

Comment: if I have autorelease I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS when pressing on a cell in the tableview

Answer (score 3):

Try it.

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
 [detail release];
 detail = nil;
```

When you push an object.Now it is added into navigation stack array, Now array owner of this object
so you should need release object which you are added in an array.

Comment: if i try to release detail as you described, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `detail` globally and release it in `dealloc:`. It may work.

Comment: Tried it, the app don't crash now when I release it in dealloc but still causes a memory leak at the same line.